# Bcache is not being utilized, slow raid/transfer rates

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, bcache

I have a 512 GB SSD serving as a cache for a 42 TB RAID using Bcache on Ubuntu Server.

To test its performance, I transferred a game containing both large and small files. When transferring files to the server, I noticed that the speed is capped at 70 MB/s, and it appears to be writing directly to the hard drive array.

When I transferring files from the server to my PC, the speed occasionally reaches 200 MB/s but frequently drops.

I am utilizing the NFS-Kernel-Server service for the file transfers.

```
/sys/fs/bcache/UUID/cache0/priority_stats shows the cache as not being used at all:
Unused:         99%
Clean:          0%
Dirty:          0%
Metadata:       0%
Average:        0
Sectors per Q:  258144
Quantiles:      [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2]

LSblk shows that all the hard drives and ssds are set up as the bcache:

sda                         8:0    0  14.6T  0 disk
└─md0                       9:0    0  43.7T  0 raid0
  └─bcache0               252:0    0  43.7T  0 disk  /export/raid
                                                     /mnt/raid
sdb                         8:16   0  14.6T  0 disk
└─md0                       9:0    0  43.7T  0 raid0
  └─bcache0               252:0    0  43.7T  0 disk  /export/raid
                                                     /mnt/raid
sdc                         8:32   0  14.6T  0 disk
└─md0                       9:0    0  43.7T  0 raid0
  └─bcache0               252:0    0  43.7T  0 disk  /export/raid
                                                     /mnt/raid
nvme1n1                   259:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
└─bcache0                 252:0    0  43.7T  0 disk  /export/raid
                                                     /mnt/raid
```

Webmin indicates that the CPU usage is approximately 30% during transfers, indicating that the speed is being limited by the hard drive.

I discovered that running the command `tail /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/stats_total/*` displays the statistics for this particular drive.

```
 sudo tail /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/stats_total/*

==> /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/stats_total/bypassed <==
6.5G

==> /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/stats_total/cache_bypass_hits <==
36

==> /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/stats_total/cache_bypass_misses <==
14982

==> /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/stats_total/cache_hit_ratio <==
97

==> /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/stats_total/cache_hits <==
46057

==> /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/stats_total/cache_miss_collisions <==
0

==> /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/stats_total/cache_misses <==
1068
```

I have followed this guide:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/bcache.html.

I have configured the RAID with the backing drive and the SSD as the cache. I have successfully registered the SSD as the cache for the RAID and enabled writeback mode.

I'm noticing that the cache drive is not being utilized.

Are there any additional settings that I need to enable or are there other ways I can test the functionality of this cache drive?

I am setting up this system for my wife's research, and I want her to be able to work off the server as a network drive.

I want the cache to function properly so she can experience decent speeds while working on it.

Comment: Your slow throughput tests seem to be when you write a lot of data to the RAID.  The 2nd paragraph of the bcache guide starts with, "*Both writethrough and writeback caching are supported. Writeback defaults to off, but can be switched on and off arbitrarily at runtime.*", and the 3rd paragraph starts with, "*Writeback caching can use most of the cache for buffering writes*".  What is your configuration with respect to `writeback` vs. `writethrough`?

Comment: /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/cache_mode shows:

writethrough [writeback] writearound none


I used this: echo writeback > /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/cache_mode from that guide. It is supposed to enable it. Not sure if this resulting output is correct though

Comment: Also, priority_stats shows 0% clean cache. I currently only have like 10gb of files on it but  I would think some of this data would have been added to clean for future reads

Comment: sequential_cutoff was the setting to configure to fix the write speeds. By default sequential_cutoff is 4Mb which means anything over 4Mb will be directly written to the hard drive. I tried 2048Mb and 4096Mb with no real change. Changing it to 0 got write speeds up to 200Mbps. I will probably narrow down the best number for this as I find out what kind of data this server gets used for.

The command is echo 0 > /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/sequential_cutoff

https://evilpiepirate.org/git/linux-bcache.git/tree/Documentation/bcache.txt

This is a useful resource for configuring bcache

Answer (score 1):

`sequential_cutoff` was the setting to configure to fix the write speeds. By default `sequential_cutoff` is 4Mb which means anything over 4Mb will be directly written to the hard drive.

I tried 2048Mb and 4096Mb with no real change. Changing it to 0 got write speeds up to 200Mbps.

I will probably narrow down the best number for this as I find out what kind of data this server gets used for.

The command is

```bash
echo 0 > /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/sequential_cutoff
```

Here is [a useful resource for configuring bcache](https://evilpiepirate.org/git/linux-bcache.git/tree/Documentation/bcache.txt).

Comment: In my case I found that cp was taking forever and `iostat` only indicated that backing hdd is in use while the NVMe was resting. Now it all makes sense, thanks.